# facing Undefined name 'BackgroundService'

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio, flutter-dependencies

```
 import 'package:flutter_background_service/flutter_background_service.dart';class 
     ReminderService extends BackgroundService {
      @override
      Future<void> onInit() async {
        // Register a callback to be called when the service is started
        BackgroundService.onServiceStarted.listen((_) {
          // Start checking for due reminders
          _checkDueReminders();
        });
    
        // Register a callback to be called when the service is stopped
        BackgroundService.onServiceStopped.listen((_) {
          // Stop checking for due reminders
        });
      }
    
      Future<void> _checkDueReminders() async {
        // Get the list of all due reminders
        final List<Reminder> dueReminders = await ReminderRepository.getDueReminders();
    
        // For each due reminder, send a notification to the user
        for (final Reminder reminder in dueReminders) {
          await BackgroundService.sendNotification(
            title: 'Reminder',
            body: reminder.message,
          );
        }
      }
    }
```

i was trying to make a service for my project i made file ReminderService and than i added  flutter_background_service: ^2.0.0 and did pubget and everything but still i am facing error Undefined name 'BackgroundService'. i tried flutter clean and everything still having same problem

Answer (score 0):

I have face this issue before on another dependency, these are steps I tried.

1. close your IDE
2. delete `pubspec.lock` file
3. go to terminal `cd ~your/project/path`
4. run `flutter clean`
5. run `flutter pub cache clean` and type `y` to confirm
6. run `flutter pub get`
7. try to build your app again.

Comment: i did all steps but still getting same error